# Microsoft Dev Center APIs returning 403

Tags: rest, uwp, azure-active-directory, windows-dev-center

I'm trying to consume dev center APIs but getting empty response for `Get all apps` endpoint even though i have couple of apps and few submissions each in partner center. I have followed all the prerequisites as outlined in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/monetize/get-all-apps but still not able to get the apps.

GET     https://manage.devcenter.microsoft.com/v1.0/my/applications returns 200 with empty response. So i assume the access token is valid.

Anybody managed to make it work with these APIs ? Am i missing anything ? I think documentation must be missing something obvious.

[image]

Comment: Did you use the access token within 60 minutes and use a global admin account? And are you able to see the apps when going directly to the Partner Center?

Comment: Thanks. I used the token within 60mins. I would get  401/403 if i use invalid/expired token. But i'm getting 200. So token is fine.  I can see the apps in partner center portal.  Can you please elaborate on `global admin account`.

Comment: As mentioned in the prerequisites, you need to be signed in with an account that has Azure AD Global Administrator permissions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/monetize/create-and-manage-submissions-using-windows-store-services

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#global-administrator

Comment: yea. i needed `global admin` account to link my AD tenant to partner center. Which i have and added the tenant to partner center correctly. I also created app registration and given it `Manager` role as described in the article.

Comment: just wondering why would i get empty response for `get apps` api. Probably the app client id i'm using doesn't have permissions to fetch apps. Even in that case it should have returned 403 but returning 200. Error is a bit misleading.

Comment: Please open a free support ticket here: [Contact Us](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support). Go to Contact us, find `Non-Technical Support - Dashboard` and choose `CHAT NOW` or 
`SUBMIT AN INCIDENT`. You could talk to the store team directly and confirm this behavior.

Comment: Sure. But this issue is technical since it involves REST apis etc. So is there anyway i can raise technical support or expedite this issue.

Comment: The store team could check the status of your account and your app which could narrow down the issue.